# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - Variáveis declaradas erradamente?

Tags: javascript

No momento em que executo a função javascript abaixo, é-me dado o erro:

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

Podem dizer-me o que está errado? Estou a declarar mal as variáveis?

```
function validate()
{


var i = 0, j = 0, counter = 0, counter1 = 0, areas, disponibilidade;

areas = document.forms[0].elements['areas[]'];

disponibilidade = document.forms[0].elements['disponibilidade[]'];

for (; i < areas.length; i++) {
    if (areas[i].checked) {
      counter++;
  }
}

for (; j < disponibilidade.length; j++) {
    if (disponibilidade[j].checked) {
      counter1++;
  }
}

if (counter==0){
alert("Selecione pelo menos uma área!")
return false;
}

if (counter1==0){
alert("Selecione pelo menos uma disponibilidade!")
return false;
}

return true;
}
```

CÓDIGO COMPLETO:

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Get the checkbox
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("sexta");
  // Get the output text
  var formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");

  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    formulario.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    formulario.style.display = "none";
    $('#formulario input').val("");
  }
}

function myFunctionSabado() {
  // Get the checkbox
  var checkBox2 = document.getElementById("sabado");
  // Get the output text
  var formularioSabado = document.getElementById("formularioSabado");

  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
  if (checkBox2.checked == true) {
    formularioSabado.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    formularioSabado.style.display = "none";
    $('#formularioSabado input').val("");
  }
}

function myFunctionDomingo() {
  // Get the checkbox
  var checkBox3 = document.getElementById("domingo");
  // Get the output text
  var formularioDomingo = document.getElementById("formularioDomingo");

  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
  if (checkBox3.checked == true) {
    formularioDomingo.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    formularioDomingo.style.display = "none";
    $('#formularioDomingo input').val("");
  }
}




var cont = 1;
//https://api.jquery.com/click/
$('#add-campo').click(function() {
  cont++;
  //https://api.jquery.com/append/
  $('#formulario').append('<div class="sexta-feira" id="campo' + cont + '">  <label>das</label><input type="time" id="sexta1' + cont + '" name="sexta1[]" oninput="Concatena2()"><label>as</label><input type="time" id="sexta2' + cont + '" name="sexta2[]" oninput="Concatena2()"><input type="hidden" id="nomeSacado' + cont + '" name="nomeSacado[]"> <button type="button" id="' + cont + '" class="btn-apagar"> - </button></div>');
});

$('form').on('click', '.btn-apagar', function() {
  var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
  $('#campo' + button_id + '').remove();
});




var cont2 = 1;
//https://api.jquery.com/click/
$('#add-campo2').click(function() {
  cont2++;
  //https://api.jquery.com/append/
  $('#formularioSabado').append('<div class="sabado" id="campo1' + cont2 + '">  <label>das</label><input type="time" id="sabado1' + cont2 + '" name="sabado1[]" oninput="Concatena5()"><label>as</label><input type="time" id="sabado2' + cont2 + '" name="sabado2[]" oninput="Concatena5()"><input type="hidden" id="nomeSacadoSabado' + cont2 + '" name="nomeSacadoSabado[]"> <button type="button" id="' + cont2 + '" class="btn-apagar2"> - </button></div>');
});

$('form').on('click', '.btn-apagar2', function() {
  var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
  $('#campo1' + button_id + '').remove();
});


var cont3 = 1;
//https://api.jquery.com/click/
$('#add-campo3').click(function() {
  cont3++;
  //https://api.jquery.com/append/
  $('#formularioDomingo').append('<div class="domingo" id="campo11' + cont3 + '">  <label>das</label><input type="time" id="domingo1' + cont3 + '" name="domingo1[]" oninput="Concatena7()"><label>as</label><input type="time" id="domingo2' + cont3 + '" name="domingo2[]" oninput="Concatena7()"><input type="hidden" id="nomeSacadoDomingo' + cont3 + '" name="nomeSacadoDomingo[]"> <button type="button" id="' + cont3 + '" class="btn-apagar3"> - </button></div>');
});

$('form').on('click', '.btn-apagar3', function() {
  var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
  $('#campo11' + button_id + '').remove();
});


function Concatena() {
  //atribui a variável nome o valor do input cujo id = nome
  var sexta1 = document.getElementById('sexta1').value;
  //atribui a variável numProcesso o valor do input cujo id = numProcesso
  var sexta2 = document.getElementById('sexta2').value;
  //concatena as duas variaveis separadas por espaço e joga no value do input cujo id = nomeSacado
  document.getElementById('nomeSacado').value = "das " + sexta1 + " as " + sexta2;

}
Concatena();


function Concatena2() {
  //atribui a variável nome o valor do input cujo id = nome
  var sexta1 = document.getElementById('sexta1' + cont).value;
  //atribui a variável numProcesso o valor do input cujo id = numProcesso
  var sexta2 = document.getElementById('sexta2' + cont).value;
  //concatena as duas variaveis separadas por espaço e joga no value do input cujo id = nomeSacado
  document.getElementById('nomeSacado' + cont).value = "das " + sexta1 + " as " + sexta2;

}
Concatena2();

function Concatena4() {
  //atribui a variável nome o valor do input cujo id = nome
  var sabado1 = document.getElementById('sabado1').value;
  //atribui a variável numProcesso o valor do input cujo id = numProcesso
  var sabado2 = document.getElementById('sabado2').value;
  //concatena as duas variaveis separadas por espaço e joga no value do input cujo id = nomeSacado
  document.getElementById('nomeSacadoSabado').value = "das " + sabado1 + " as " + sabado2;

}
Concatena4();


function Concatena5() {
  //atribui a variável nome o valor do input cujo id = nome
  var sabado1 = document.getElementById('sabado1' + cont2).value;
  //atribui a variável numProcesso o valor do input cujo id = numProcesso
  var sabado2 = document.getElementById('sabado2' + cont2).value;
  //concatena as duas variaveis separadas por espaço e joga no value do input cujo id = nomeSacado
  document.getElementById('nomeSacadoSabado' + cont2).value = "das " + sabado1 + " as " + sabado2;

}
Concatena5();

function Concatena6() {
  //atribui a variável nome o valor do input cujo id = nome
  var domingo1 = document.getElementById('domingo1').value;
  //atribui a variável numProcesso o valor do input cujo id = numProcesso
  var domingo2 = document.getElementById('domingo2').value;
  //concatena as duas variaveis separadas por espaço e joga no value do input cujo id = nomeSacado
  document.getElementById('nomeSacadoDomingo').value = "das " + domingo1 + " as " + domingo2;

}
Concatena6();


function Concatena7() {
  //atribui a variável nome o valor do input cujo id = nome
  var domingo1 = document.getElementById('domingo1' + cont3).value;
  //atribui a variável numProcesso o valor do input cujo id = numProcesso
  var domingo2 = document.getElementById('domingo2' + cont3).value;
  //concatena as duas variaveis separadas por espaço e joga no value do input cujo id = nomeSacado
  document.getElementById('nomeSacadoDomingo' + cont3).value = "das " + domingo1 + " as " + domingo2;

}
Concatena7();








function validate() {
  var i = 0,
    j = 0,
    counter = 0,
    counter1 = 0,
    areas, disponibilidade;
  areas = document.forms[0].elements['areas[]'];
  disponibilidade = document.forms[0].elements['disponibilidade[]'];

  for (; i < areas.length; i++) {
    if (areas[i].checked) {
      counter++;
    }
  }

  for (; j < disponibilidade.length; j++) {
    if (disponibilidade[j].checked) {
      counter1++;
    }
  }

  if (counter == 0) {
    alert("Selecione pelo menos uma área!")
    return false;
  }

  if (counter1 == 0) {
    alert("Selecione pelo menos uma disponibilidade!")
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<form method="POST" action="roda.php" onsubmit="return validate()">
  <div id="formulario5">

    <!--NOME-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Nome: </label>
      <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" required>
    </div>

    <!--APELIDO-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Apelido: </label>
      <input type="text" name="apelido" placeholder="Apelido" required>
    </div>


    <!--SEXO-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Sexo: </label>
      <select name="sexo">
        <option value="masculino" required>Masculino</option>
        <option value="feminino" required>Feminino</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <!--IDADE-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Idade: </label>
      <input type="number" name="idade" min="12" required>
    </div>

    <!--MORADA-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Morada: </label>
      <input type="text" name="morada" placeholder="Morada" required>
    </div>

    <!--CONTACTO-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Contacto: </label>
      <input type="tel" name="contacto" required><br>
    </div>

    <!--EMAIL-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>E-mail: </label>
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required>
    </div>

    <!--HABILITAÇÕES LITERÁRIAS-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Habilitações literárias: </label>
      <input type="text" name="habilitacoes" placeholder="Habilitações Literárias" required>
    </div>

    <!--RESTRIÇÕES ALIMENTARES-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Possui algum tipo de restrição alimentar? (deixar em branco se não se aplicar)</label>
      <input type="text" name="restricoes_alimentares" placeholder="Restrições alimentares">
    </div>

    <!--AREAS DE INTERESSE-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Áreas de Interesse: </label><br>
      <input id="interesse1" type="checkbox" name="areas[]" value="bilheteira">Bilheteira<br>
      <input id="interesse2" type="checkbox" name="areas[]" value="guarda-roupa">Guarda-Roupa<br>
      <input id="interesse3" type="checkbox" name="areas[]" value="venda de artesanato">Venda de artesanato<br>
      <input id="interesse4" type="checkbox" name="areas[]" value="restauracao">Restauração<br>
      <input id="interesse5" type="checkbox" name="areas[]" value="figuracao">Figuração<br>
      <input id="interesse6" type="checkbox" name="areas[]" value="legiao">Legião<br>
    </div>


    <label>Disponibilidade: </label><br>
    <!--SEXTA-FEIRA-->

    <div id="formulario2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" id="sexta" name="disponibilidade[]" value="sexta-feira" onclick="myFunction()">sexta-feira<br>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="formulario" style="display:none">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>das</label>
        <input type="time" id="sexta1" name="sexta1[]" oninput="Concatena()">
        <label>as</label>
        <input type="time" id="sexta2" name="sexta2[]" oninput="Concatena()">
        <input type="hidden" id="nomeSacado" name="nomeSacado[]">
        <button type="button" id="add-campo"> + </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--SABADO-->
    <div id="formulario21">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" id="sabado" name="disponibilidade[]" value="sabado" onclick="myFunctionSabado()">sábado<br>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="formularioSabado" style="display:none">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>das</label>
        <input type="time" id="sabado1" name="sabado1[]" oninput="Concatena4()">
        <label>as</label>
        <input type="time" id="sabado2" name="sabado2[]" oninput="Concatena4()">
        <input type="hidden" id="nomeSacadoSabado" name="nomeSacadoSabado[]">
        <button type="button" id="add-campo2"> + </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--DOMINGO-->
    <div id="formulario211">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" id="domingo" name="disponibilidade[]" value="domingo" onclick="myFunctionDomingo()">domingo<br>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="formularioDomingo" style="display:none">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>das</label>
        <input type="time" id="domingo1" name="domingo1[]" oninput="Concatena6()">
        <label>as</label>
        <input type="time" id="domingo2" name="domingo2[]" oninput="Concatena6()">
        <input type="hidden" id="nomeSacadoDomingo" name="nomeSacadoDomingo[]">
        <button type="button" id="add-campo3"> + </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--TRANSPORTE-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Possui transporte próprio? </label><br>
      <input type="radio" name="transporte" value="sim" required> Sim
      <input type="radio" name="transporte" value="nao" required> Não<br>
    </div>



    <!--VOLUNTÁRIO-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Já foi voluntário de alguma edição anterior do Festival e/ou em alguma atividade promovida pela associação? </label><br>
      <input type="radio" name="voluntarioAPPACDM" value="sim" required> Sim
      <input type="radio" name="voluntarioAPPACDM" value="nao" required> Não<br>
    </div>


    <!--AUTORIZAÇÃO DE IMAGENS-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Autoriza o uso da sua imagem em conteúdos multimédia (fotografia e vídeo), como forma de publicitação no presente website e nas demais redes sociais do Festival?</label><br>
      <input type="radio" name="autorizaImagem" value="sim" required> Sim
      <input type="radio" name="autorizaImagem" value="nao" required> Não<br>
    </div>






  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </div>
</form>






</html>
```

Comment: `document.forms[0].elements['areas[]']` ou `document.forms[0].elements['disponibilidade[]']` é `undefined`, verifique os nomes no JS e no HTML

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam , editei e postei o código completo. Se você executar, vai ver que funciona, porém, quando eu colo o código na minha página Wordpress, ele me dá o erro que eu disse

Comment: Tome cuidado com o momento em que chamas o método! Nesse caso você pode estar sofrendo com o assincronismo entre ter carregado a view (html) completamente ou não.
Rodando localmente, por exemplo, pode ser que já tenha sido carregado, no Wordpress ainda não. Verifique se variável está preenchida, antes de chamar o método .lenght

Comment: tente mudar as variáveis dessa forma `areas = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="areas[]"]')` e `disponibilidade = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="disponibilidade[]"]');`

Comment: Não encontro o erro que referes no código. Testaste correr o código que tens aqui na pergunta?

Comment: @MáttheusSpoo , DEU CERTO!!! OBRIGADO!!!

Comment: @Sergio , como disse não havia nenhum erro quando tentava correr o código normalmente. O problema aconteceu quando o implementei no Wordpress, porque essa função era saltada. Ao substituir as variáveis por `areas = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="areas[]"]');` e `disponibilidade = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="disponibilidade[]"]');` consegui resolver o problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao substituir as variáveis por `areas = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="areas[]"]');` e `disponibilidade = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="disponibilidade[]"]');` consegui resolver o problema.